# Octave inaccurately solving systems of linear equations?

Tags: matlab, numpy, octave

I found that Octave inaccurately solves system of equations.

```
k= [1.0000e+015,  -2.6667e-001,  3.3333e-002;-2.6667e-001,  5.3333e-001,  -2.6667e-001;3.3333e-002,  -2.6667e-001,  2.3333e-001];
f = [0;6.66667;41.66667];
x = (k\f)
x1 = inv(k)*f
```

`x = (k\f)` gives

```
-3.8893e-031
-1.9136e+001
 1.1192e+001
```

`x1 = inv(k)*f` gives

```
 4.8339e-014
 2.3752e+002
 4.5003e+002
```

There is difference between two answers. Just to check whether other software can solve it, I tried in python numpy.

```
import numpy as np
k = np.array ([[1.0000e+015,  -2.6667e-001,  3.3333e-002],[-2.6667e-001,  5.3333e-001,  -2.6667e-001],[ 3.3333e-002,  -2.6667e-001,  2.3333e-001]])
f = np.array([[0],[6.66667],[41.66667]])
x = np.linalg.solve(k, f)
print(x)

[[  4.83388655e-14]
 [  2.37521517e+02]
 [  4.50034428e+02]]
```

And it solves correctly.
I want to use operator `\` in octave to solve equations (I guess this is recommended method in MATLAB). Any suggestions?

Using Octave 4.2.x on Windows.

EDIT:

Why the answer is downvoted? Here is what GNU Octave says https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/:

> Drop-in compatible with many Matlab scripts

Try running the same script in MATLAB and think yourself.

Commenters blame on ill-conditioned matrix. A good solver should able to solve with sufficient accuracy (as numpy and MATLAB do).

Comment: I don't think so. It is specific to octave operator \ and probably algorithm of that operator. Other method works, but not recommended. If there were problem in floating points, both methods should not work.

Comment: Did you happen to notice the warnings when you tried these? "warning: matrix singular to machine precision, rcond = 6.66612e-17"

Comment: Yes, nonetheless `numpy` gives more accurate answer. In fact, octave `inv` function too. Look at the magnitude of errors in octave \ and `inv`, when both methods give the warning.

Comment: That is a really poorly-conditioned matrix. It's no surprise that you're getting substantial error.

Comment: I think `k\f` is not same as `inv(k)*f`, rather it's numerically more stable pseudo-inverse, which is `inv(k'k)*(k'f)`: that's why the results are different.

Comment: Did you actually *check* whether the "correct" output was any better than the "wrong" output?

Comment: Certainly. I am doing research in computational physics. Not always we have nice and well conditioned system. Software such as octave should be able to give sufficiently accurate results. I believe a well written LU decomposition would give better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Summary: Octave developers have chosen to return the  "minimum norm solution" for a (flagged) singular system of equations.

===============

The first element of `k` is much larger than all the others, while the corresponding term of `f` is 0.  In the `x1` solution

```
4.8339e-014
2.3752e+002
4.5003e+002
```

the first term is virtually 0.

Performing the solve on the remaining 2x2 matrix, produces the same values:

```
>> inv(k(2:end,2:end))*f(2:end)
ans =    
   237.52
   450.03

>> k(2:end,2:end)\f(2:end)
ans =
   237.52
   450.03
```

and in `numpy`:

```
In [518]: np.linalg.solve(k[1:,1:],f[1:])
Out[518]: 
array([[ 237.52151737],
       [ 450.0344278 ]])
```

=================

For some reason, the `\` solver is more sensitive to matrix singularity.

```
>> k\f
warning: matrix singular to machine precision, rcond = 6.66612e-17
warning: matrix singular to machine precision, rcond = 6.66612e-17
```

and yes, testing this solution shows that it's way off

```
>> k*(k\f)
ans =
    5.4761
  -13.1904
    7.7144

>> rcond(k)
ans =    6.6661e-17
>> rcond(k(2:end,2:end))
ans =  0.083327
```

I'm not sure of the significance of this, but the `numpy` `lstsqr` solver returns the same bad-values as `k\f`:

```
In [525]: np.linalg.lstsq(k,f)
Out[525]: 
(array([[ -3.88925778e-31],
        [ -1.91360857e+01],
        [  1.11917602e+01]]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 2,
 array([  1.00000000e+15,   6.89292234e-01,   7.73677656e-02]))

>> pinv(k)*f  #  Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse
ans =
  -3.8893e-31
  -1.9136e+01
   1.1192e+01
```

http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42181 - claims that this is documented.  For an singular, or under or overdetermined equation Octave returns the  "minimum norm solution", as opposed to a "basic solution" (MATLAB's choice).

http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Solvers_for_singular.2C_under-_and_over-determined_matrices